# p-columnFilter with p-multiSelect doesn't work Primeng angular table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

Can someone help me figure out why my multiselect filter is not working please? The multiSelect displays correctly the different options, the values present in the column which field is "direction". Once I click on any value in the options, the table makes all rows disappear as if the keyword was not present in any row in the column "direction"

I really don't understand why that is, and how exactly this p-multiSelect works, the documentation being quite poor about it.I set it up exactly like it is here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/table/filter

the column data for field direction looks something like this ['SW', 'N', 'SW', 'NE'....]. (24 strings in array)

this is html

```
<th pSortableColumn="direction">Wind Direction <p-sortIcon  field="direction"></p-sortIcon>
            <p-columnFilter field="direction" matchMode="in" display="menu" [showMatchModes]="false" [showOperator]="false" [showAddButton]="false">

              <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
                  <p-multiSelect [ngModel]="value" [options]="windDirections" placeholder="Any" (onChange)="filter($event.value)" optionLabel="direction">
                      <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
                          <div class="p-multiselect-wind-option">
                            <span class="pi pi-compass mr-5px"></span>
                            <span style="margin-left: 5px;">{{option.direction}}</span>
                          </div>
                      </ng-template>
                  </p-multiSelect>
              </ng-template>
          </p-columnFilter></th>
```

here is ts

```
  windDirections: Wind[];

this.windDirections = [    // options for the multiselect filter
      new Wind('N'),
      new Wind('NE'),
      new Wind('NW'),
      new Wind('S'),
      new Wind('SW'),
      new Wind('SE'),
      new Wind('E'),
      new Wind('W'),
    ];

// wind model
export class Wind {
  constructor(public direction: string) {}
}

// here is function which format the wind direction column based on the direction 

checkWindDirection(value) {
    if (value >= 0 && value <= 22) {
      return new Wind('N').direction;
    } else if (value > 22 && value <= 67) {
      return new Wind('NE').direction;
    } else if (value > 67 && value <= 112) {
      return new Wind('E').direction;
    } else if (value > 112 && value <= 157) {
      return new Wind('SE').direction;
    } else if (value > 157 && value <= 202) {
      return new Wind('S').direction;
    } else if (value > 202 && value <= 247) {
      return new Wind('SW').direction;
    } else if (value > 247 && value <= 292) {
      return new Wind('W').direction;
    } else if (value > 292 && value <= 337) {
      return new Wind('NW').direction;
    } else return new Wind('N').direction;
  }

// then in ngOnInit subscribe i am using the above function like this which then is pushed to weatherData array and weatherData is used in [value] for table to make the columns

const windDirections =
          historicalWeatherData.hourly.winddirection_10m.map((item) =>
            this.checkWindDirection(item)
          );
```

if i change the multiselect filter to normal basic text filter it works and its filtering based on what i type but no luck with this multiselect picker filter

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. I added `optionValue="direction"` attribute to the p-multiselect and it works now!